# Drupal Nice Menus dropdown hidden by content below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal

I've set up a Drupal menu using the Nice Menus module but my drop-down menu is evidently hidden by the content below it.  I've tried all manner of z-indexes and overflow:visible that I can think of and I can't manage to get this working. Using Firebug I can see that the jQuery is properly changing the display to block and visibility to visible, yet the sub-menu is still hidden.

Here's the development site where you can see the HTML/CSS: http://tentenstudios.com/clients/hshf/.  The menu item with the drop down list is "Group Information."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in your dev site via firebug and it worked (firefox 38.0.5) :
Delete overflow property in row class
1220.css line 15

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1220px;
    min-width: 755px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Add "position: relative;" in #maincontent_container :
styles.css line 83

```
  #maincontent_container {
        background-image: url("/clients/hshf/sites/all/themes/hshf/images/maincontent_corn_bg.png");
        background-position: center bottom;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Tell me if if it works for you

Comment: Huh, that's the one -- I know I tried removing overflow but I never tried position:relative.  Now I'll have to see how that affects the rest of the layout and the responsiveness of it all.  Thanks a bunch!